# How to create latex table too big that out of border with tabularray package?

Tags: tables, tabularray

I have a table created by the `tabularray` package, the table size is larger than the width of the page and so it is partially hidden on the right side as shown below, how to align the table to move back to the left and not lose the text. Thank you very much!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,right=2cm,left=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justifying
\begin{document}
 \noindent
\begin{tblr}{width=1.2\linewidth,hlines,vlines,colspec={Q[1,c]Q[6,l]Q[1.5,c]Q[2,c]Q[2,c]Q[2,c]},rows={1.5cm,m},row{1}={1.5cm,c}}
\textbf{STT}& \textbf{Tên trang thiết bị}& \textbf{ĐVT}& \textbf{Số lượng}&\textbf{Tình trạng}& \textbf{Ghi chú}\\
1&Điều hòa&Cái&01&Mới& \\
2&Máy tính &Bộ&01&Cũ&\\
3&Nhiệt kế tự ghi&Cái&01&Mới\\
4&Ẩm kế&Cái&01&Mới\\
5&Tủ thuốc&Cái&04&Cũ\\
6& Phần mềm kết nối liên thông dữ liệu&Bộ&01&Mới&Công ty Viettel
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, with `width=1.2\linewidth` you already say that the table will be too wide. Change that to `width=\linewidth`.

Comment: Unrelated: you can bold the content of 1st row using the command `row{1} = {font=\bfseries}`. In that case you won't need to write the `\textbf` command again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following ME:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            hmargin={2cm,3cm},vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
 \noindent
\begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines,
             colspec={c X[3,l] *{4}{X[1,c]} },
             rows={1.5cm,m},
             row{1}={font=\bfseries, c}
             }
STT & Tên trang thiết bị    & ĐVT   & Số lượng  & Tình trạng    & Ghi chú   \\
1   & Điều hòa              & Cái   & 01        & Mới           &           \\
2   & Máy tính              & Bộ    & 01        & Cũ            &           \\
3   & Nhiệt kế tự ghi       & Cái   & 01        & Mới           &           \\
4   & Ẩm kế                 & Cái   & 01        & Mới           &           \\
5   & Tủ thuốc              & Cái   & 04        & Cũ            &           \\
6   & Phần mềm kết nối liên thông dữ liệu
                            & Bộ    & 01        & Mới           & Công ty Viettel   \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

**Addendum:**
In the case, that you like to have table wider than text width, but still visible on the page, than the use of the `adjustwidth` macro define in the `changepage` package be a way todo this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            hmargin={2cm,3cm},vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
 \noindent
\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}
\begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines,
             colspec={c X[2.4,l] *{4}{X[c]} },
             rows={1.5cm,m},
             row{1}={font=\bfseries, c}
             }
STT & Tên trang thiết bị    & ĐVT   & Số lượng  & Tình trạng    & Ghi chú   \\
1   & Điều hòa              & Cái   & 01        & Mới           &           \\
2   & Máy tính              & Bộ    & 01        & Cũ            &           \\
3   & Nhiệt kế tự ghi       & Cái   & 01        & Mới           &           \\
4   & Ẩm kế                 & Cái   & 01        & Mới           &           \\
5   & Tủ thuốc              & Cái   & 04        & Cũ            &           \\
6   & Phần mềm kết nối liên thông dữ liệu
                            & Bộ    & 01        & Mới           & Công ty Viettel   \\
\end{tblr}
\end{adjustwidth*}
\end{document}
```

After second compilation the result of above MWE is:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: I think the OP wanted to horizontally center the 1st row. The 2nd column of the 1st row is left-aligned (and I prefer it).

Comment: @Imran, you are right. I oversee option `c` for the first row. Added now.